# Python - preprocessing dataframes data in a class

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented, design-patterns

**Context**

I am building an algorithm that automatically assigns a planning to drivers. However there is a lot of pre-processing and reused outputs. I try to structure it in a maintainable way.

**Questions**

I created a class `Availability` that represents the number of hours each driver has each day. There is a base planning, but for some use cases, additional (sometimes compute intensive) processing needs to be done.

The solution I came up (simplified version of code below) initializes the class with all the necessary data in the constructor, but with a default of `None` for the optional data (in this example: `preplanned` and `holidays`). That way if I'm in a simple case, I can just call the class without the optional data.

My questions are:

- Is this ok? Or should I get them out of the constructor and place them as method arguments (ie: `get_availability_without_preplanned(preplanned)` and `get_availability_fully_processed(preplanned, holidays)`)
- Are there other improvements?

Some reasons behind my logic:

- The actual code base will be much larger and some `get_xxx()` could be chained and cached
- Initializing everything in the constructor ensures for example `preplanned` is always the same for an instance, and not modified for each method call

**code**

````
from typing import List
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class Availability:
    """
    Class representing the hours available per day for each driver
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        raw_availability: pd.DataFrame,
        preplanned: pd.DataFrame = None,
        holidays: List = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.columns = ["date", "driver_id", "availability"]
        self.base_availability = self.clean_raw_data(raw_availability)

        # Optional
        self.preplanned = preplanned
        self.holidays = holidays

    def clean_raw_data(self, raw_availability: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Format to a basic format
        """
        base_availability = raw_availability.loc[:, self.columns]
        base_availability["availability"] = base_availability["availability"].astype(float)
        return base_availability

    def get_availability_without_preplanned(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Base availability per driver, dedecuted with preplanned hours
        """
        availability_without_preplanned = self.deduct_preplanned(self.base_availability)
        return availability_without_preplanned

    def get_availability_fully_processed(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Availability per driver, with all preprocessing
        """
        availability_without_preplanned = self.get_availability_without_preplanned()
        availability_fully_processed = self.set_availability_to_zero_on_holidays(
            availability_without_preplanned
        )
        return availability_fully_processed

    def deduct_preplanned(self, availability: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Deduct preplanned hours from the availability of the drivers
        This is an example, but imagine this would be compute intensive
        """
        if self.preplanned is None:
            raise TypeError("No preplanned hours passed in class constructor")

        aggregated_preplanned = (
            self.preplanned.groupby(["date", "driver_id"])
            .agg({"hours": "sum"})
            .reset_index()
            .rename(columns={"hours": "hours_to_deduct"})
        ).astype(float)

        preplanned_deducted_availability = pd.merge(
            how="left",
            left=availability,
            right=aggregated_preplanned,
            left_on=["date", "driver_id"],
            right_on=["date", "driver_id"],
        ).fillna(0)

        preplanned_deducted_availability["availability"] = (
            preplanned_deducted_availability["availability"]
            - preplanned_deducted_availability["hours_to_deduct"]
        )
        preplanned_deducted_availability = preplanned_deducted_availability.loc[:, self.columns]
        return preplanned_deducted_availability

    def set_availability_to_zero_on_holidays(self, availability: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Deduct preplanned from the availability of the drivers
        This is an example, but imagine this would be compute intensive
        """
        availability["availability"] = np.where(
            availability["date"].isin(self.holidays), 0, availability["availability"]
        )
        return availability


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Mockup data
    raw_availability = pd.DataFrame(
        {"date": [20201224, 20201225], "driver_id": [1, 1], "availability": [8, 8]}
    )
    preplanned = pd.DataFrame({"date": [20201224], "driver_id": [1], "hours": [2]})
    holidays = [20201225, 20211225]

    # Complex case: everyting is defined
    availability1 = Availability(
        raw_availability=raw_availability, preplanned=preplanned, holidays=holidays
    )
    print(availability1.base_availability)
    print(availability1.get_availability_without_preplanned())
    print(availability1.get_availability_fully_processed())

    # Simple case: optional arguments preplanned and holidays are left out
    availability2 = Availability(raw_availability=raw_availability)
    print(availability1.base_availability)

```
````